# Multiple sites more than 1 sub domain, where do the CSS and JS go for this?

Tags: php, laravel

This comes as a type of unique question that can't really be found anywhere else.

I know that Laravel recommends that you keep your index in a folder called public then have all your CSS and JS in the same folder, but I have a few questions.

What happens when you have multiple sites such as an admin (admin.example.com) or more than 1 sub domain, where do the CSS and JS go for this?

Also, what exactly is the resources/assets folder used for if not css and js?

Comment: Similar Q here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40932021/1531971 Alos, might want to search on "laravel multiple sites" and see the "Laracasts" links.

Comment: You may want to title this question better

Comment: you can use any folder and any url. You can even include files from a public CDN server.